# entry point for packager

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm just starting out with react native. Everything was going ok but now when I run 'react-native run-ios' the packager is looking for js files in

```
<project-root>/node_modules/react-native/packager
```

instead of

```
<project-root>
```

If I run 'node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start'
it looks for files in the correct location.

This is happening in my existing project and if I create a new project using react native init. It started after I installed a new npm module. I've since reverted the change, re-installed modules, cleared the tmpdir cache, rebooted computer etc. Can I explicitly configure the packager entry point?

Any help greatly appreciated

C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with RN 0.45, I have also encountered this problem today after upgrading from 0.42.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14246

The temporary solution until RN is fixed (next release?) is to run:

```
npm start -- -reset-cache
```

You can also try:

```
npm run start -- --root <mydir>
```

This will cause the packager to look in the correct location.

Until this is corrected it's a pain, as it means we have to invoke the reset every time the packager is started either from XCode or `react-native run-ios`.

The next release is later this month: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.46.0-rc.0

**Update**
This has now been fixed in [release 0.45.1](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14246)

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was reverting to 0.43.1 (a version that I have other apps working with): delete node_modules, change package.json under dependencies to "react-native": "0.43.1", and `npm install`. Verify your version with `react-native --version`, and run again.