# I'm getting a "Cannot find entry file index.android.js" error after upgrading to react-native 0.45 using react-native-git-upgrade

Tags: android, react-native

Before the upgrade I was using react-native 0.42 and everything worked. I even tried running a new project and still the same error. How do I fix this? Should I revert back to the older version?

[React Native App Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCeR3.png)

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413022/entry-point-for-packager/44415654#44415654)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [entry point for packager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413022/entry-point-for-packager)

Answer (score 1):

that's how i've solved the issue in my Windows PC:

in the first admin's cmd.exe typed:

```
netstat -a -b -o
```

Found PID of 8081 server.
Then i killed this proccess by typing

```
taskkill /pid 1234
```

where '1234' is your PID found before.
open normal cmd.exe and typed:

```
react-native start
```

open another normal cmd.exe and typed:

```
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if the 8081 port is used by any other app or service. If you are on a Linux or Mac, head to terminal and then

```
lsof -i :8081
```

then you will get a list of ports, just select the one with name node and then

```
kill -9 <port-no>
```

and then finally

```
npm start
```

This should fix the problem