# React Native 0.45 - Cannot find entry file index.ios.js

Tags: react-native

I just updated my react native project to version 0.45
and when using this command : react-native run-ios on the root of this project 
I am getting this error :

Cannot find entry file index.ios.js in any of the roots ....
and i can see that the server is trying to look for JS files in

Looking for JS files in
   /Users/someUser/Code/ReactTest/node_modules/react-native/packager

when using this command : npm run start -- --root .

i can see that the server is looking for js file in the correct location

Looking for JS files in
   /Users/someUser/Code/ReactTest

and every thing is working from here

why the react-native run-ios is try to look in the wrong location ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [entry point for packager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413022/entry-point-for-packager) - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14246

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today. As noted [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14246) it has been corrected as of version 0.45.1, but this turned out to be a red herring for me.

The most telling problem in my case was that `index.ios.js` didn't actually exist anywhere in my project, only in some places in `node_modules`. It turns out that, because I'd initialised the project with the `create-react-native-app` command, I had to:

`npm run eject`

You can read more about the eject command [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject).

---

If you still have issues, try the below.

1. Check your dependency versions. Here are my RN packages:

   ```
   "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
   "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
   "react-native": "^0.45.1"
   ```
2. Update your dependency managers. These worked for me:

   ```
   $ yarn --version
   0.18.1

   $ npm --version
   4.6.1
   ```
3. Clean your cache(s). **WARNING - CONTAINS `rm -rf`, COPY WITH CARE**.

   ```
   watchman watch-del-all
   rm -rf ./node_modules
   yarn cache clean
   rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*
   yarn install
   npm start -- --reset-cache
   ```
4. After that last `npm start`, hit `CTRL+C` and ensure there are no dormant npm processes running in the background. Then, try `react-native run-ios` again.

Answer (score -1):

The react-native launched new release 0.45 a few days back. So, the commands to create a react-native application and running locally have many differences.

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app
```

Then run the following commands to create a new React Native project called "AwesomeProject":

the new way of creating a react-native application as follows

```
create-react-native-app AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject
npm start
```

Please follow the official documentation for creating an application and running the application on locally. hope the below link will help you.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Once you've set these up, you can launch your app on an Android Virtual Device by running `npm run android`, or on the iOS Simulator by running `npm run ios`(macOS only).

Enjoy, Happy coding :)